# ¿Se puede hablar de POO en PHP?

Tags: php, poo

Es una duda que tengo desde hace tiempo.

Hace tiempo quería preguntar, esto, y lanzo la pregunta con la esperanza de que no sea cerrada por basarse en opiniones... Si eso ocurre podría ser para mi una respuesta: **No**.

**La duda que tengo es si en PHP podemos hablar de Programación Orientada a Objetos (POO) en el estricto sentido de la palabra o si por el contrario en PHP sólo se pueden aplicar algunos principios de POO.**

Espero respuestas, si las hay, basadas en documentación y en pruebas.

Cuando veo los ejemplos del Manual de PHP al respecto, o los llamados [*métodos mágicos*](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) da la impresión de que se violan conceptos básicos de la POO, como es el caso de crear `setters`  de acceso público.

La pregunta concretamente es la siguiente: **¿Podemos decir que con PHP se puede hacer POO en el estricto sentido de la palabra? ¿Por qué?**

Comment: Apoyo tu pregunta, totalmente pienso que no es basada en opiniones, ni que va contra la tendencia del sitio, pues es una pregunta concreta con una respuesta cerrada, ya que sería ilógico decir que dos personas pueden tener una idea diferente de que paradigma sigue PHP, ya sea objetos, estructurado o multiparadigmas. No pueden haber dos opiniones diferentes, porque si fuera del caso, una de las dos estaría mal.

Comment: Yo uso PHP y Java (muy usado para ejemplarizar la POO). La mayor diferencia sería en cuanto al **tipado**, cambia mucho el modo de plantear la programación. Mecanismos como los *métodos mágicos* o los *Traits* no se muy bien como encajarlos. Se puede decir que la forma de aplicar el paradigma varía adaptándose a las características de cada lenguaje. Quizá habría que reducir el problema a partes más pequeñas: ver si PHP permite cumplir con todas las características de la POO y en qué grado. Creo que estás son: ***abstracción***, ***encapsulamiento***, ***modularidad*** y ***herencia***.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> ¿Es PHP estrictamente POO?:

Para responder esto comprobemos varios puntos:

## 1) Citando la documentación PHP:

> A partir de PHP 5, el modelo de objetos ha sido reescrito para tener
>   en cuenta un mejor rendimiento y mayor funcionalidad. Este fue un
>   cambio importante a partir de PHP 4. PHP 5 tiene un modelo de objetos
>   completo.

Según la documentación, a partir de PHP 5, tenemos un modelo de objetos completo:

- **Visibilidad:** public, private y protected.
- Clases
- Objetos y propiedades.
- Métodos públicos y privados.
- Definición de clases y propiedades estáticas.
- Métodos mágicos como:

  - `__get()`
  - `__set()`
  - `__call()`
  - `__construct()`

`PHP POO ESTRICTO + 1;`

## 2) Fundamentos de POO y su papel en PHP:

En la POO podemos encontrar características que son fundamentales para considerar al lenguaje como OO, entre ellos:

1) **Abstracción**

2) **Herencia**

3) **Encapsulamiento**

3) Ocultamiento

4) Polimorfismo

5) Modularidad

6) Recolección de Basura

Segun lei, los teóricos de la POO, se centraron en los 3 principales puntos(los que están en **negrita**) como los fundamentales de la POO.

Ahora, revisemos si PHP cumple con los fundamentales:

## Empleando los fundamentos de POO en PHP:

```
// Declarar la clase es *encapsulamiento*
// Al usar extends estamos usando "herencia"
Class Entidad extends EntidadMayor
{
    public $atributo;
    //Ocultar las funciones del exterior es *ocultamiento*
    public function obtenerAtributo(){
        return $this->atributo;
    };
}
// Al crear una instancia estamos *abstrayendo*
$objeto = new Entidad();
$objeto->atributo = "valor";
$objeto->obtenerAtributo();
```

Se cumplen los 3 fundamentos de POO.

`PHP POO ESTRICTO + 1;`

## 3) Métodos Mágico VS Método de la Clase

Para acceder a las propiedades de una clase tenemos dos métodos, el método clásico y el método mágico:

***Método Clásico***:
En este metodo definimos nuestros propios `getters` y `setters`:

```
Class Entidad
{
    public $atributo;
    public function obtenerAtributo() {
        return $this->atributo;
    }
    public function cambiarAtributo($dato) { 
        $this->atributo = $dato;
    }
}
$objeto = new Entidad();
$objeto->atributo = "valor";
$objeto->cambiarAtributo("nuevoValor");
$objeto->obtenerAtributo(); // nuevoValor
```

***Método Mágico***:
En este método utilizamos los métodos mágicos que trae PHP, como son `__get()` y `__set()`:

```
Class Entidad
{
    public $atributo;
    public function __get($property) {
        if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
            return $this->$property;
        }
    }
    public function __set($property, $value) {
        if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
            $this->$property = $value;
        }
    }
}
$objeto = new Entidad();
$objeto->set($atributo,"valor");
$objeto->get($atributo); // valor
```

**¿En qué momento uso que tipo de métodos?:**

La respuesta la encontramos en el apartado "Sobrecarga" de la documentacion oficial de PHP.

**Pero antes entendamos unos conceptos básicos:**

**¿Qué es sobrecarga?:**

> **En programación orientada a objetos** la sobrecarga se refiere a la posibilidad de tener dos o más funciones con el **mismo nombre** pero
>   funcionalidad diferente, es decir, estas realizan acciones diferentes en función de **diferente número y/o Tipos** de Parámetros.

**¿Existe entonces la sobrecarga en PHP?**:

NO, recordemos que PHP no es tipado:

```
$entero = 4; // Entero.
$entero = "4"; // String.
$string = array(); // Array.
```

Por lo tanto, en PHP no existe la sobrecarga por tipos de parámetros.

Aparte no podemos controlar la cantidad de argumentos que son pasados a la funcion, ejemplo Javascript, usando arguments[],por lo tanto tampoco existe sobrecarga por numero de parametros.

Pero a PHP no se le escapa de las manos, ya que crea: "los métodos Mágicos" y junto a esto una **simulacion** de **sobrecarga**.
*(algunos dicen que esta propiedad de PHP esta mal nombrado)*

**Citando: *http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.overloading.php***

> La sobrecarga en PHP ofrece los medios para *crear* dinámicamente
>   propiedades y métodos.
>
> Se invoca a los métodos de sobrecarga cuando se interactúa con
>   propiedades o métodos **que no se han declarado o que no son visibles en
>   el ámbito activo**.
>
> La interpretación de PHP de "overloading/sobrecarga" es distinta de la mayoría de los lenguajes orientados a objetos. 
>   **La sobrecarga tradicionalmente ofrece la capacidad de tener múltiples métodos con el mismo nombre, pero con un tipo o un número distinto de parámetros.**

Entonces si en PHP no existe la sobrecarga: **¿que papel cumplen los metodos magicos para simularla?**

**¿Que son los métodos mágicos?:**

- Son funciones que permiten cambiar la funcionalidad interna de las
  clases a través de la implementación de ciertos métodos.
- Son llamados automáticamente por PHP ante determinados eventos.
- Por lo que nos permite ejecutar codigo cuando ocurran dichos eventos.
- Gracias a su capacidad para modificar las clases, tendremos ahora el poder de adaptar los parametros recibidos, los tipos , y la forma en la que opera una clase,las instancias,y los metodos get/set.

Podriamos entonces decir que:

> Los métodos mágicos fueron creados para poder simular la sobrecarga.
>   Entonces dichas funciones no se usan para ir en opuesto a los
>   fundamentos POO sino para hacer PHP aun más parecido a POO, adaptando su lenguaje no tipado a la capacidad de verificar tipo de datos al modificar como interactuan los **metodos accesores** de la clase.

**NOTA:** *cabe destacar que lo que hariamos con estos métodos mágicos sería poder modificarlos para opacar (shadowing) a la funcion predeterminada que tienen dentro de la clase.*

**Veamos un ejemplo de sobrecarga usando un método mágico:**

```
<?php
class MiClase
{
    public function __construct()
    {

        // Almacenamos los argumentos ingresados.
        $parametros= func_get_args();

        // Retornamos el número de argumentos ingresados.
        $numeroParametros = func_num_args();

        // Creamos el constructor con el numero de parametros.
        $constructor ='__construct'.$numeroParametros;

        // Buscamos el metodo dentro de nuestra clase.
        if (method_exists($this,$constructor)) {
            call_user_func_array(array($this,$constructor),$parametros);
        }
    }
    public function __construct0() {
        echo "Cero argumento";
    }
    public function __construct1($x) {
        echo "Una argumento: $x";
    }
    public function __construct2($x, $y) {
        echo "Dos argumentos: $x y $y";
    }
}
$objeto0 = new MiClase("0"); // llamará a construct0
$objeto1 = new MiClase("1"); // llamará a construct1
$objeto2 = new MiClase("1","2"); // llamará a construct2
```

Usando el método mágico `__construct()`, estamos sobrecargando al constructor para que reaccione según los parámetros pasados, llamando *al mismo* metodo.

Ahora usemos otro método por ejemplo `__call()`:

**¿Que función tiene __call()?**

-Permite capturar la invocación de métodos no existentes.

- Esté método puede ser re-definido para cubrir las necesidades del sistema o como en este caso, proporcionar sobrecarga.
- Aprovechando está funcionalidad podemos controlar la función a la que estamos llamando y redirigir a la función concreta a la que hacemos referencia.

**Veamos un ejemplo:**

```
class Ejemplo {

  // Ejecutaremos Prueba el CUAL NO EXISTE pero gracias a __call lo creamos verificando
  // que este exista en un array.
  // Call lo usamos con este formato: __call($nombreDelMetodo, $argumentos)

  function __call($nombreMetodo, $argumentos) {
    $metodosAceptados = array("Pruebas");
    if(!in_array($nombreMetodo, $metodosAceptados)) {
      echo "$nombreMetodo no existe en los métodos disponibles";
    }
    $numeroArgumentos = count($argumentos);
    if($numeroArgumentos == 0) {
      $this->Pruebas1();
    } else if($numeroArgumentos == 1) {
      $this->Pruebas2($argumentos[0]);
    } else if($numeroArgumentos == 2) {
      $this->Pruebas3($argumentos[0], $argumentos[1]);
    } else if($numeroArgumentos == 3) {
      $this->Pruebas4($argumentos[0], $argumentos[1], $argumentos[2]);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  function Pruebas1() {
    echo "Hola pasaste cero argumentos<br>";
  }
  function Pruebas2($nombre){
    echo "Hola $nombre, pasaste 1 argumento<br>";
  }
  function Pruebas3($primerNombre, $segundoNombre){
    echo "Hola $primerNombre $segundoNombre, pasaste dos argumentos<br>";
  }
  function Pruebas4($primerNombre, $segundoNombre, $edad){
    echo "Hola $primerNombre $segundoNombre, ya tienes $edad años, pasaste tres argumentos<br>";
  }
}
$objeto = new Ejemplo();
$objeto->Pruebas();
$objeto->Pruebas("John");
$objeto->Pruebas("John", "Smith");
$objeto->Pruebas("John", "Smith", 60);
```

En este ejemplo sobrecargamos a nuestra clase con un número distinto de parámetros y ademas de distinto tipo. En conclusión es posible sobrecargar (simulado) en PHP.

`PHP POO ESTRICTO + 1`;

**ESPERA**: *¿No sería entonces Polimorfismo igual que sobrecarga?, porqué si es así estas haciendo polimorfismo y no sobrecarga?*:

**NO**,polimorfismo se refiere a un conjunto de métodos con el **mismo Nombre** e **igual Número de Parámetros y Tipos**, pero que se encuentran definidos en diferentes Clases, anteriormente pasamos diferentes tipos de datos.

**Veamos un ejemplo de polimorfismo:**

```
// Definimos las clases
class Poligono
{
    function calculo() {
        echo 'El area depende del tipo de polígono';
    }
}
class Cuadrado extends Poligono
{
    function calculo()  {
        echo 'area de un cuadrado : a=l*l<br>';
    }
}
class Rectangulo extends Poligono
{
    function calculo()  {
        echo 'area de un rectangulo : a=b*h<br>';
    }
}
class Triangulo extends Poligono
{
    function calculo()  {
        echo 'area de un triangulo : a=(b*h)/2<br>';
    }
}

// Definimos la funcion que hara la llamada polimórfica al método cuadrado
// Es decir adaptaremos la función definida a cualquiera de las clases.

// NOTA: En la definición de la función definimos el tipo parámetro que pasamos por referencia, esto no es obligatorio en PHP, pero nos ayuda a entender el concepto y así poder aplicarlo en otros lenguajes más estrictos.

// Pasamos un objeto de la clase Poligono
function area(Poligono $objeto) {
    $objeto->calculo();
}
// Creamos los objetos necesarios
$cuadrado = new Cuadrado;
$rectangulo = new Rectangulo;
$triangulo = new Triangulo;

// Ejecutamos la función encargada de realizar la llamada polimórfica
area($cuadrado);
area($rectangulo);
area($triangulo);

// La función `area()` nos muestra la fórmula correcta en cada una de sus ejecuciones para cada tipo de figura geometrica, sea este Cuadrado, Rectangulo, Triangulo, pese a que en su definicion inicial hayamos especificado que el objeto es del tipo "Poligono" haciendo referencia a la clase base de cada objeto.
```

`PHP POO ESTRICTO +1;`

## 4) Nuestros métodos mágicos de interés:

> `__set()` se ejecuta al escribir datos sobre propiedades inaccesibles.
>
> `__get()` se utiliza para consultar datos a partir de propiedades
>   inaccesibles.

Citando la documentacion de sobrecarga en PHP encontramos esto:

> Se invoca a los métodos de sobrecarga cuando se interactúa con
>   propiedades o métodos que no se han declarado o que no son visibles en
>   el ámbito activo.

Tenemos dos puntos de interés: **Ámbito Activo** y **Propiedades
Inaccesibles**

**Ambito activo**:

> El ámbito de una variable es el contexto dentro del que la variable
>   está definida.

**Propiedades innacesibles**: Son aquellas propiedades que bien estan ocultas, o no estan definidas.

Citando lo anterior, como **la sobrecarga** usa los **metodos magicos**, y estos debes de poder acceder a propiedades innacesibles.

Se fundamenta la razón de ser métodos públicos, ya que, te deben permiten **obtener** valores que no están en tu ámbito, ademas de **crearlos** dinamicamente si NO existen, cumpliendo su rol, interactuar con métodos/propiedades innacesibles.

**Veamos el ejemplo en una clase:**

```
Class Entidad
{
    // defino $atributo como privado.
    private $atributo;
    public function obtenerAtributo() {
        return $this->atributo;
    }
    public function cambiarAtributo($dato) { 
        $this->atributo = $dato;
    }
}

$objeto = new Entidad();
$objeto->atributo = "valor";
$objeto->cambiarAtributo("nuevoValor");
$objeto->obtenerAtributo(); // nuevoValor
$objeto->otroAtributo = "valor";
```

En este caso al usar `obtenerAtributo( )` o `cambiarAtributo( )` estamos trabajando bajo atributos que están definidos dentro de la clase. Pero en el último llamado de `otroAtributo` estamos definiendo un valor que no existe.

Aqui entra el papel de `__set` y `__get`, los cuales nos permiten trabajar bajo propiedades o métodos inexistentes:

1) Si los quisiera redifinir para controlar como obtener y cambiar variables usaría:

```
public function __set($propiedad,$valor) {
            //
        }
public function __get($propiedad) {
            //
        }
public function __call($metodo, $argumentos) {
           //
}
```

2) Estos métodos nos permiten controlar el acceso o el cambio de propiedades.

3) No son sustitutos de los `getters/setters`, ya que, nos permiten trabajar en modos que de la forma clásica daría error, más que todo **son para manejo de errores**, ejemplo obteniendo/cambiando atributos que no existen, comparando con JavaScript podrían usarse como si quisiéramos evitar que se crearan objetos sin `new`.

4) Podría definirse a los métodos mágicos como los `Object Watchers` de Javascript, ya que estos crean propiedades inexistentes para funcionar, pero claro esta golpea en el rendimiento del código.

## Entonces sabiendo cuando usarlos, ¿Cual es mas eficiente?

### Ocurre un problema, son públicos y pueden acceder a mis propiedades privadas, ¿que hago?:

Como es fácil violar la encapsulación en PHP:

**Veamos un ejemplo**:

```
class Produccion
{
}
$objeto = new Produccion();
$objeto->hackeado = 'boom';
```

Tendremos dos soluciones:

1) Si trabajas con mas personas: **Documentar**.

2) Si no queremos documentar, para evitar usar dichos metodos, haremos lo siguiente, re-declarar los métodos mágicos:

```
class Produccion
{
    public function __set($name,$value){
        throw new Exception ('No');
    }
    public function __get($name){
        throw new Exception ('No de nuevo');
    }
    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        throw new Exception ('Stop');
    }
}
$objeto = new Produccion();
$objeto->hackeado  = 'boom'; //  Uncaught Exception: No
$objeto->hackeado; //  Uncaught Exception: No de nuevo.
$objeto->hackeado(); //  Uncaught Exception: Stop.
```

A pesar de que estos métodos "crean" propiedades y métodos dinámicos, en ninguno de los casos funcionan como se esperaba **porque los redefinimos**, así podemos evitar esos posibles "fallos" de encapsulamiento.

**¿Y si quiero utilizar mis propios metodos get/set?**:

Sencillamente agregamos nuestros propios métodos privados:

```
    class Produccion
    {
    private $atributo = 4;
        public function __set($name,$value){
            throw new Exception ('No');
        }
        public function __get($name){
            throw new Exception ('No de nuevo');
        }
        public function __call($metodo, $argumentos) {
            $metodosAceptados = array("tus","metodos","get","set");
            if(!in_array($metodo, $metodosAceptados)) {
                 throw new Exception ('Stop');
        }
    }
    private function get(){
        return $this->atributo;
    }
    private function set($valor){
        return $this->atributo = $valor;
    }
}
$objeto = new Produccion();

// Si queremos usar el get y set privados totalmente, los des-habilitamos en el __call, para evitar que los llamen sino queremos que sea así
$objeto->get(); // 4
$objeto->set(60);
$objeto->get(); // 60
```

Entonces, podemos observar que aunque si pueden generar aberturas de seguridad en el encapsulamiento de PHP, podemos proteger las propiedades, por su misma capacidad de servir (los metodos magicos) como administradores de propiedades y metodos mas adaptables a las necesidades.

`PHP POO ESTRICTO + 1;`

## En conclusión: PHP: SI ES POO ESTRICTO.

1) Cumple con los fundamentos de la POO:

- Herencia.
- Abstracción.
- Encapsulamiento.

2)Tiene los elementos básicos como son:

- Objetos, clases y métodos.
- Visibilidad privada, protegida y pública
- Metodos privados y públicos
- Puede emplear propiedades estáticas
- Sobrecargar sus métodos.

3) Puede ademas tener polimorfismo y sobrecarga (gracias a los métodos mágicos):

4) Tiene métodos mágicos con los que:

- Ampliar las capacidades de PHP como POO.
- Administrar los errores en PHP, y permiten redefinir las propiedades accesoras del objeto (aumentado así la encapsulación).
- Los métodos mágicos se pueden opacar (shadowing).

Comment: Te has trabajado bien esta excelente respuesta. Sólo me queda una duda. Aquí: `public function construct1($x)
    {
        //código;
    }

    public function construct2($x, $y)
    {
        //código;
    }
}

$objeto1=new MiClase('1'); // llamará a construct1
$objeto2=new MiClase('1','2'); // llamará a construct2` no me queda claro por qué llama a `construc1` o a `construct2` según los parámetros. ¿Si hubiese otro constructor debería llamarse `construct3`?

Comment: gracias, lo hice leyendo muchas preguntas y disputas en foro de que si o no era posible sobrecargar y demas, ya te respondo.

Comment: @A.Cedano tuve que reescribir el codigo, porque no funciona del todo bien

Comment: @A.Cedano, exactamente como dices , porque el concatena el numero de parametros al string, pero me estaba dando un problema con los argumentos, asi que utilice la llamada con otra funcion.

Comment: Esta respuesta se parece más a una documentación. La marqué como favorito para consultarla para aprender de lo que has publicado acá. Esto mereció un `+1`.

Answer (score 3):

Según wikipedia el paradigma de PHP es:

> Multiparadigma: imperativo, funcional, orientado a objetos, procedural, reflexivo.

Y la definición del paradigma de POO es:

> La programación orientada a objetos (POO, u OOP según sus siglas en inglés) es un paradigma de programación que usa objetos en sus interacciones, para diseñar aplicaciones y programas informáticos. Está basada en varias técnicas, incluyendo herencia, cohesión, abstracción, polimorfismo, acoplamiento y encapsulamiento.

Si se puede hacer POO en el estricto sentido de la palabra, pero también hay que ver que los que vamos empezando en POO solemos mezclar los diferentes paradigmas. Entre mis proyectos encuentro continuamente saltos entre un paradigma y otro, sobre todo en pequeñas escalas. Cuando trabajas en C todo es imperativo y es fácil leerlo, así que en ocasiones escribes código en Java o PHP  siguiendo este paradigma. Pero en realidad si es OO. Lo mismo me sucede en Python. En un principio no utilizaba clases propias, todo lo hacía con funciones, ni hablar de herencia o abstracción.

Con el tiempo vas adquiriendo más práctica en uno u otro paradigma. En este caso no depende tanto de PHP, si no de cuando conoces en realidad del paradigma y cuanto sabes aplicarlo. Aunque en esto último habrá quien difiera.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Sobre los métodos mágicos. En python todo se puede sobreescribir y acceder desde cualquier lugar. No existen los private, ni los public. Existen, pero son menciones sobre el formato del código. Por ejemplo, una variable _VAR no debe ser accedida desde fuera de la clase. Son convenciones a las que se llegan. A eso se le llama ocultación y es una de las características de POO. JAVA es muy estricto en este sentido, porque está pensado para trabajo en equipo. Un líder, desarrolladores Jr, etc. Python no, es más libre. Confía en las buenas prácticas del programador. Y pues PHP tiene sus queveres en estas ideas. De todos modos cuando desarrollas un proyecto en POO lo menos que quieres es tener que estar accediendo a métodos de otras clases y sobreescribirlos. Crea confusión. A mi en lo personal solo me interesa el get y set con los resultados que me describe. Acceder a los métodos mágicos tiene algunas complicaciones que no quiero.